# How to write response of streamReader into textfile in c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a socket program in c#.I want to save the response of the server into textfile.Here is the code that i am using for it..

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
var serverResponse = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

How to save this response in text file.
Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(var textFileWriter = new StreamWriter("textFile.txt"))
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    var serverResponse = streamReader.ReadLine();

    textFileWriter.WriteLine(serverResponse);
}
```

This way you can save your stream into a file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mentioned coe.

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("debug.txt", true))
 {
   writer.WriteLine("whatever you text is");
 }
```

The second "true" parameter tells it to append.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Comment: I am getting response from server in serverResponse and you have not used it in your code ..how will server response save to text file